# Find string at start of text using gnu

Tags: gcc, gnu

In gnu, I want to test the version of the gcc being used.
The version I am checking for is "4", but in fact any minor version of "4" is acceptable.
Therefore if the gcc is "4.1" or "4.3.5", that is fine.

If I run the following:

```
ifeq "$(findstring 4.,$(GCC_VERSION))" "4."
```

.... do stuff ...

It would test to true for GCC_VERSION value of 4.1, but it would also test to true for a GCC_VERSION with a value of "2.4.3", which I do not want.

So what I want to know is how to test for the first two characters of the GCC_VERSION. If these equal "4.", then I want the test to pass.

Unfortunately, I do not know how to test manually gnu files/scripts like this, the code is in a file that is part of a massive build system the functioning of which is out of my hands. If you have any idea how I could test such a script manually, I would appreciate it too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "gnu" you appear to mean [GNU Make](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/). [GNU](https://www.gnu.org/home.en.html) is vastly more than that.

If it's safe to assume that the values of `GCC_VERSION`, from wherever you get them, won't begin with dots, then in GNU Make it would suffice to test if the first token delimited by a dot is "4":

```
ifeq "$(firstword $(subst ., ,$(GCC_VERSION)))" "4"
$(info version 4.x.y)
else
$(info not version 4.x.y)
endif
```

See [8.2 Functions for String Substitution and Analysis](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Text-Functions.html)
in the manual

Comment: Thanks, that does the job!